# How can I store site setting in MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm making a minimalist admin panel. I need to store site settings on MongoDB. But the site should be store only one "setting class" on db because there is no multiple follow us TwitterURLs for the site.

Here is my class and properties;

```
        public class Setting
        {
            [BsonId]
            [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
            public string Id { get; set; }
    
            public string TwitterUrl { get; set; }
        }
```

So when I insert this to the db, it has an id. When i insert another setting, second rows appear that i don't need. The setting class should be singular on the db. I need to write, read and update only one row not multiple rows. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
What have you tried already?

Comment: Mongo operates on collections, there is no specific way to work with single object collection, you have to emulate this behaviour. For selecting you just query first object, for storing you can drop all data in collection and then save your object.